# What is the third variable in a matrix partial correlation?

Tags: matrices, statistics, correlation

I believe the below background information is necessary to explain my question...

**Background Information:**

> I have a square 2D matrix of variables that represent the interaction
> between any two positions in a protein's sequence. I then compare each
> column of interactions using Pearson's correlation and store that
> value in a new correlation matrix. This is shown graphically in the
> linked image.
>
> [image: Interaction matrix to correlation matrix.]
>
> The next step in this protocol is to take the partial correlation. For that I use the below equation where Where rxy-1 is the correlation coefficient for a given position (x, y) in the inverted correlation matrix, and rxx-1 and ryy-1 are the corresponding diagonal values.
>
> [image: Partial Correlation Equation]

On to the question itself, I found an alternative way of calculating partial correlations from this kind of data in [this paper](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004182&type=printable). It has two equations, shown below. As far as I can tell, the right equation is identical to the pc equation I have been using thus far, except with different notation, and it is shown as being equivalent to the left equation.

[image: Alternate Partial Correlation Equations]

**My question is:** In converting from the right equation to the left equation, where is the third variable, C, coming from. A and B are equivalent to my X and Y position values, so how can I extrapolate a third C dimension from my 2D correlation matrix?

I have very little mathematical background, so don't hesitate to ask me for important information that I have overlooked. Thanks in advance for any help you all can render!!

**Edit:** Thanks to @GoldenGateBridge 's great explanation I think I now better understand the 3 variable partial correlation equation, at least the version used in the above paper. The right 2 var equation uses inverse covariance as its basis for PC calculation while the 3 var equation is calculated from the correlation matrix. I drew up a graphical representation of my understanding below (the numbers aren't accurate calculations, its just for example).

[image]

Comment: First, notice in the paper, the right equation has a negative out front, and uses the inverted covariance matrix, not correlation matrix. As for how the left equals the right, it’s not possible to tell just by looking at it. But it’s only for the case where there are three positions in your protein. For your protein you would have to compute the correlation between say position 3 and 5 holding the other ~35 positions given. A recursive formula can be found on Wikipedia, but since it’s not reputable I’m not linking it here. Therefore, it appears much easier to use the right expression. Good luc

Comment: @GoldenGateBridge I appreciate the reply!! This is interesting as I had overlooked the fact that the paper is using an inverse covariance matrix. That being said, my implementation is supposed to be with the inverse *correlation* matrix.

The source of this question is that my scripts aren't working as they should, so I thought converting to the 3 variable equation on the left would provide me with some insight on why my implementation of the 2 variable partial correlation is wrong.

Comment: Here is the recursive formula for the implementation for your ≈38×38 grid: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/… ; Note in the case where Z is a single variable, this reduces to the left formula (3 positions total). Below that, is the matrix inversion method. "Note that only a single matrix inversion is required to give all the partial correlations between pairs of variables" making this computationally less expensive. It does not appear that these involve inverse correlation matrix. tl;dr: The third variable would be the third position if your protein grid only was $3\times 3$

Comment: @GoldenGateBridge I found the wiki article you mentioned, and with you tl;dr I *think* I was able to figure out the setup for this system. I added a simple figure to my question to demonstrate my current understanding based on your help. I definitely understand a lot more about these calculations now, but I'm now not sure they will prove useful in my work! Still, thank you a ton for your assistance!!

Comment: Nice!! Yeah, I think your picture makes sense to me. :)